# GUI Python script run at startup

Tags: startup

I have a Python script that uses Tkinter that I'd like to start when then the RPi boots up.  I've edited the /home/pi/.bashrc file to include the following lines:

```
cd /home/pi/python/eth2o
python main.py
```

The script (main.py) won't start unless I start a terminal session on the RPi.  How can I fix this so that the Python script starts without having to start a terminal session?  Thanks for any help in advance!

Answer (score 1):

`.bashrc` it's only sourced when bash is run (so when a terminal session is opened for example).

You need to look into autostart scripts to launch programs after your window manager is loaded. Create a desktop file in  `/etc/xdg/autostart/<some-name>.desktop` and put something like this inside it:

```
[Desktop Entry]
Name=SomeName
Exec=/usr/bin/python3 /home/pi/python/eth2o/main.py
```

Comment: Thanks for the reply, but it still doesn't work.  My .desktop file looks like this:

[Desktop Entry]
Name=SomeName
Exec=/usr/bin/python3 /home/pi/python/eth2o/main.py

I chose not to give it a name.

Comment: @dwburger , don't forget to add Type=Application and Terminal=false as follows:

[Desktop Entry]
Name=SomeName
Exec=/usr/bin/python3 /home/pi/python/eth2o/main.py
Type=Application
Terminal=false

Answer (score 0):

I found a solution to my question:

In the /home/pi/ folder:

```
sudo nano startapp.sh 
#!/bin/bash
cd /home/pi/python/eth2o python3 main.py
```

Then edit the autostart file:

```
sudo nano /etc/xdg/lxsession/LXDE-pi/autostart
```

Put your startapp in the autostart file:

```
@sh /home/pi/startapp.sh
```

Answer (score 0):

This solution perfectly worked for me on Armbian under `/etc/xdg/autostart/<some-name>.desktop`:

```
[Desktop Entry]
Name=SomeName
Exec=/usr/bin/python3 /home/pi/python/eth2o/main.py
Type=Application
Terminal=false
```

Without having `Type` and `Terminal` my script was not being run!

Answer (score 0):

Here is the complete flow of how to use Python GUI based app on startup of any Linux based system like raspi, jetson device or x64/x86 device.

First Create an Autostart Directory if not exist:

```
mkdir ~/.config/autostart
cd ~/.config/autostart
```

Then create a sh file (You can create anywhere this file)

```
sudo nano sinage.sh
```

Write inside file

```
#!/usr/bin/env bash
cd full_path_working_directory
source /home/user_name/anaconda/bin/activate env_name
python path_to_python_file/python_file_name.py
```

Create a Desktop app (Must create inside startup folder)

```
sudo nano myapp.desktop
```

Write inside file

```
[Desktop Entry]
Version=1.0
Name=Test
Comment=Test the terminal running a command inside it
Exec=bash -i path_to_shfile.sh
Icon=utilities-terminal
Terminal=true
Type=Application
Categories=Application;
```